# Define column's width in Asp.net table using % identifier

Tags: html, css, asp.net, width

I am trying to design a simple UI consisting labels and textboxes but my controls are going beyond the width of parent control. Here is the html for the table.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Bold="true">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth10">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth20">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth10">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth20">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth10">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth20">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell >
            <asp:Label ID="TextBox7" Runat="Server" Text="User ID"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell >
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Runat="Server"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="Server" Text="UserName"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Runat="Server"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" Runat="Server" Text="Badge No"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
         <asp:TableCell>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

and here is the output for the above html
[image]

First row containing textBoxes for Account ID/Name/No is OK but the below table's controls are going outside the parent container whose cssClass is

```
.content-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;
```

}

```
.CellWidth10 { width: 10%; }
.CellWidth20 { width: 20%; }
```

But if I add more control's to the first table, its controls also go outside the parent container.

So How do I correctly pace controls like we do in WPF using tables and then defining width/height using percentages?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it on this way

```
<asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth10" Width="10%">
<asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="CellWidth20" Width="20%">
```